# How to get the Author type Label Language

Tags: author, multi-language, labels

I am working on a plugin and I need to have the word 'Author' appear in whatever language is set in the wordpress settings.

I have achieved this for the words: Posts and Pages using this code:

```
    $post_type = get_post_type_object( 'page' );
    $postTitle = $post_type->label;
```

How can this be done to get the label for 'Author'? I know that author is not a post type, so how can this be achieved?  THANKS! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at:
https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

You should probably just use a get_text function such as
$author = __('Author');

Comment: Thank you oferwald for the suggestion, I am looking for a more direct solution that requires no specific translation by me or the user, because I know that somewhere WordPress has already translated this.